# Python Encoding Problems using ASCII Code

Tags: python, character-encoding, ascii, chr, ord

Write a function

```
shiftLetter(letter, n)
```

whose parameter, `letter` should be a single character. If the character is between `"A"` and `"Z"`, the function returns an upper case character  
n
positions further along, and "wrapping" if the +  
n
mapping goes past `"Z"`. Likewise, it should map the lower case characters between `"a"` and `"z"`. If the parameter `letter` is anything else, or not of length 1, the function should return `letter`.

Hint: review functions `ord()` and `chr()` from the section, as well as the modulus operator `%`.

---

Down below is what I worked so far. It should return to A after alphabet is over, but it's not working properly from alphabet x. I guess..? I should subtract 90(Z) - 65(A) in ASCII table for x,y,z but confused about that.

```
def shiftLetter(letter,n):
    if letter >= 'A' and letter <= 'Z':
        return chr(ord(letter) + n )
   elif letter >= 'a' and letter <= 'z':
        return chr(ord(letter) + n )

print(shiftLetter('w',3))
```

Comment: You haven't implemented the "Wrapping" part of the assignment.   If you go beyond "Z" or 'z', you need to subtract 26.

Comment: Yes, I conceptually know that concept, but having difficulties coding it. Could you let me know how to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mod operator to wrap the alphabet:

```
def shiftLetter(letter,n):
   if letter >= 'A' and letter <= 'Z':
        return chr((ord(letter) - ord('A') + n) % 26 + ord('A') )
   elif letter >= 'a' and letter <= 'z':
        return chr((ord(letter) - ord('a') + n) % 26 + ord('a') )

print(shiftLetter('w',3))   # z
print(shiftLetter('E',3))   # H
print(shiftLetter('Y',3))   # B
print(shiftLetter('f',26))  # f
print(shiftLetter('q',300)) # e
```

Output

```
z
H
B
f
e
```